# AutoScaling ec2 instance with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to autoScale this ec2 instance please guide me how to do it. Any template that might be helpful so that I can get started with the autoscaling. I am attaching only ec2 instance template which I want to autoScale.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "shifa-vpc"
Resources:
  webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: webserver-sg
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-09d95fab7fff3776c # ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      #IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
      #KeyName: ky-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref webserver
Outputs:
  ec2:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-server"

  sgGroupId:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !GetAtt webserver.GroupId
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-sgid"
```

I am new to cloudformation and I am in training.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html

Comment: @jordanm I have seen the documentation having trouble references the ec2 instance properties. Can you please give a template of how I can autoscale this ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Amazon have some [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html) for AutoScaling instances.

Importantly EC2 instance resources are not part of the autoscaling configuration within CloudFormation.

Instead you would use either a [Launch Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-launchtemplate.html) or a [Launch Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) resource. The Launch Template is newer so preferably you should use this. These will define the instance configuration such as volumes, instance type etc.

The other component is the [Autoscaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) this will reference either one of previous components and define how the instance should scale.

If you're trying to scale an existing instance you will need to [make an AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) from it first and the reference it.

AWS has an example template with autoscaling groups [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ec2-autoscaling-php-app-demo/blob/master/cf-templates/template-test.yml).